# Map just ONE object to another (DTO) with Java8

Tags: java, lambda

can you tell me if exist some pretty way to map one entity object to another dto object? When I needed convert `List<ObjEntity>` to `List<ObjDTO>` I created that function:

```
public class Converter {
public static Function<ObjEntity, ObjDTO> MYOBJ_ENTITY_TO_DTO = objEntity -> {
    ObjDTO dto = new ObjDTO();

    dto.setId(objEntity.getId());
    dto.setName(objEntity.getName());
    dto.setNote(objEntity.getNote());
    // ...

    return dto;
    };
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
List<ObjDTO> dtos =  objEntitiesList.stream().map(Converter.MYOBJ_ENTITY_TO_DTO).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But what if I need convert just ONE object? Should I use that function `MYOBJ_ENTITY_TO_DTO` for that and how? Or what is the best practice? Yes, I can do classical function in Converter class like that:

```
public static ObjEntity dtoToEntity(ObjDTO dto) {
   // map here entity to dto and return entity
}
```

but it is old style. Exist some new practice in java 8? Something similar like my example for list by lambda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ObjDTO dto = MYOBJ_ENTITY_TO_DTO.apply(entity);
```

I see the other way around more often: instead of `MYOBJ_ENTITY_TO_DTO`, define `entityToDto` as a method and use

```
List<ObjDTO> dtos =  objEntitiesList.stream().map(Converter::entityToDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

for lists.